# Target li that has a child ul

Tags: css, sass

Is there a way using SASS to target an `<li>` if it contains a `<ul>`?
I have this:

```
ul {
  li::before {
  content: "\2022";
  color: $color;
 }
}
```

with this html

```
<ul>
 <li> // problem li
  <ul>
   <li>stuff</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

'`<li>` // problem li' is showing the bullet and I don't want it to.

I tried

```
li {
  ul & {
   &:before {
   display: none;
  }
}
```

I'm not sure how to do this. I could apply a class to `'<li> // problem li'`, but I'd like to keep it all in css if possible

Thank you

Comment: Apply a class to the `li` and do it that way because currently there is no way to target a parent based on the child using css

Comment: No, currently in CSS there's no way to target a node that's not the last one in your selector chain. `::before` also doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: With SASS you can do: `li { ul & ul &{ property: value; } }`